# Java performance timing library

Tags: java, performance, timing

I frequent wrap code in a [System.nanoTime()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) pair in order to timing it. Something like:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();    
methodToBeTimed();
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

There is any good timing library that helps with this problem? Also homegrown code will be accepted.

NB

A profiler is not a solution here, since I want to enforce some time constraints in my unit tests, so I want to timing methods **programmatically**.

Comment: I don't understand what the "problem" is that you are trying to solve.   You have one line at the top, and one more line at the bottom to give you elapsed time.  And you have one variable to hold it.  You could wrap this in a class, or use the Stopwatch class, but you won't really reduce the complexity of the code in any way: you still will need one line at the top, and one line at the bottom.  Is it that you want help recording and tracking a large number of such timings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Ignore this answer as the project is no longer active**

I haven't used it but I came across [perf4j](https://github.com/perf4j/perf4j) recently.

Comment: @Mark: never heard about it. Thanks very much!

Comment: You may even draw graphs with perf4j, with the integrated servlet. It's quite  good.

Comment: Link is broken :-(

Answer (score 9):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I am also often using this tip to time my code and just wrote the following simple Eclipse -> Surround With template:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
${line_selection}${cursor}
long totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
System.out.println("Total time = " + totalTime);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm a netbeans user -:)

Answer (score 8):

JUnit 4 got a built-in timing-contraint functionality.

@Test(timeout=X)

should do the trick. X is the maximum number of milliseconds the method is allowed to run.

Comment: yes, this is a very basilar implementation, essentialy I'm loooking for @Test(timeout=X, repeat=N) then display the average

Answer (score 7):

there is [StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html) from commons-lang, it also allows you to split timer.

Comment: nice to see it but it only encapsulates System.nanoTime/System.currentTimeMillis calls

Comment: its always easier to use than the default version ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Spring you already have nice class called [StopWatch](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) in your classpath for this propose.

Answer (score 2):

[JETM](http://jetm.void.fm/) is a good library for doing this. It can also provide with mins, maxs and averages, plus can generate informative graphs.

Comment: Looks unmaintained, for anybody interested in this. Runs only on HTTP and JavaDoc is inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

Tried [JPerf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jperf/) ?

Comment: Use google cache to see usage, Alternatively check the link to xjperf: http://code.google.com/p/xjperf/

Comment: it seems a frontend for iperf, that is "a modern alternative for measuring maximum TCP and UDP bandwidth performance". It is right?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of help are you looking for with this problem?  You have the basics in place.  You get the elapsed time in Nanoseconds, accurate to whatever resolution the underlying OS/Hardware is capable of.

Also... and I know you said no profilers... but I have had outstanding experience with [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com).  It provides an API that you can use to control profiling from the outside.  Depending on what your exact problem is, this one might be worth having a look at.

Answer (score 1):

[**Caliper**](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/)

And in addition to reading the wikis on that site, i recommend reading:

- ["Writing a Java Micro-benchmark"](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.microBenchmark)
- ["Java theory and practice: Anatomy of a flawed microbenchmark"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Something new on the market is [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). It's made under the umbrella of the openjdk project.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using [Java Simon](https://github.com/virgo47/javasimon) (formerly [on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/javasimon/)), and it seems awesome! A simple set of stopwatches and counters with few dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A simple wrapper for commons-lang [StopWatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/StopWatch.html) which take into account multi threading environment, when stop is not invoked leap stat is not counted and 'failed leaps count' incremented (you may not include stop in finally block if the behavior is desired), exposes live statistic via JMX and deliver consolidated serializable result over the network. Example usage:

```
private PerfStat methodPerf = new PerfStat("method.under.test");
...
public void myMethod() {
    methodPerf.start();
    ...
    long timeNs = methodPerf.stop();
}
```

dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.droolsassert</groupId>
    <artifactId>da-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think your implementation for `minLapTime` would work, since it is initialized with the lowest possible value: 0. It should probably be initialized with (and reset to) `Long.MAX_VALUE`.